# Thread safety of nested calls

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have two libs, one is thread safe called `class A`, The other lib called `class B`, which used `class A` to realize functions.

```
class A {
 public:
  void Get() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    do_something
  }

  void Put() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
    do_something
  }
 private:
  std::mutex mutex_;
};

class B {
 public:
  void Get() {
    a.Get();   
  }

  void Put() {
    a.Put();
  }
 private:
  A a;
};
```

So is class B thread safe?

I know that judging whether the thread is safe depends on whether the operation is atomic. If the put operate is not atomic then it's not thread safe. According to the above requirements, I think class B is not an atomic operation, so it is not thread-safe?

When the operation is not atomic, it may not be thread safe. for example we add some operate like below, Is it right?

```
class B {
 public:
  void Get() {         // But Get is not atomic!!!
    do_some_thing();   // atomic
    a.Get();          // atomic
    do_some_thing();   // atomic
  }

  void Put() {
    do_some_thing();   
    a.Put();
    do_some_thing();
  }
 private:
  A a;
};
```

Comment: If all it does is call a single method in a thread safe implementation then what would make it unsafe?

Comment: Unless you over-simplified the example, `B` would be thread-safe, since all it does is delegate some calls to one and the same object `a` which is assumed to be thread-safe..

Comment: The new edits changed the question to one that cannot be really answered. Now, it all depends on what's inside those opaque `do_some_thing` calls. *If* they don't use `a` *and* if whatever other data they use is accessed in a thread-safe way then `B` can be thread-safe. Otherwise it *may* not be thread-safe, though it could still be as a side-effect of the serialized access to `a`. But again, it all depends on the actual code, which is not shown. This is precisely where a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help.

Answer (score 1):

Thread safety concerns about the race conditions and data races.

Now, Since the methods of class `B` don't use any data directly but via delegating other methods in class `A` that as you said are thread-safe, the methods in `B` are thread-safe.

Comment: When the operation is not atomic, it may not be thread safe. I updated the problem description